# Code igniter File-Upload is not getting the value

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Im done with this and its working with my previous project. Right now, I am doing a new project and tried to copy and paste my code in file-upload.. It has no value.. My problem is that why my file upload is not getting the value?

Note: I already declared the form in my helper, and may folder is already existed.. Name of my column is img_jumbotron, version of my CI is 3.3(latest)

**View**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload New Image</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="titleLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header modal-header-success">
        <button type="button" class="close btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="titleLabel">New Image</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="text-content">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-5">
                  <br>
                  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?= base_url().'Administrator/addContent/'?>">
                    dklfjkdf
                    <input type ="text" name ="example">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Image</label>
                      <input type="file" required class="form-control" name="userfile"/> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <span class="pull-right">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload File</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           </span>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function addContent()
    {
      $config['upload_path'] = './uploaded/';   
      $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
      $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;          
      $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">', '</div>');
      $example = $_POST['example'];
      $example = $this->input->post('userfile');
      print_r($example);die;
      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE || !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
      { 
          echo ('ksldfhsdj');
      } 
      else 
      {

          $content = array(
              'img_jumbotron' => $this->input->post('userfile'),
                'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
              );

          print_r($content);die;
          $this->AdminModel->addContent($content); 
          redirect('Administrator/headContent');
      }
```

**Model**

```
public function addContent($content)
    {

        $content = array(
            'img_jumbotron' => $this->input->post('userfile'),
            'img_jumbotron' => $this->upload->data('file_name')
            );
        $this->db->insert('content', $content);
    }
```

Comment: HTML headache right there...

Comment: What do you mean @JBES?

Comment: Just remarking on the large number of `DIV`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use developer tools on your browser and check the NETWORK (for chrome I guess) tab and check if your application is sending the file.

and also:

```
action="<?=base_url().'Administrator/addContent/'?>"
```

I think you should remove the equal sign on this "`<?=`".

Comment: Sir the equivalent of <?php echo ?> is that ( <?= ?> )

Comment: I see.. haven't used that.. Well then, I think you need to use dev tools for this problem.. :)